# Can I install VS on two machines with one license?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, licensing

I am an adjunct professor teaching database and programming classes.  I own a desktop and laptop both running Windows.  I own an Academic copy of VS 2010 and have it installed/activated at home.

Starting in the Fall I will be teaching C# .NET programming with VS 2010.  However, the laptop at the college with it installed is a 5 year old POS.  Can I install VS 2010 and activate with the same license on my laptop as I do with my desktop?  Or does this violate the license with Microsoft?  I thought about buying another copy - but the Academic reseller I deal with said I am only allowed to buy one copy a year.  Both are used for Academic purpose - my day job provides me with a laptop so I am not worried they would ever think I am doing non-academic work with these - but I really need to have VS on both.

Thanks,
MDV

Comment: You can always use an express version, which is totally free.

Comment: yes he can use the express version, but in order to teach a well rounded course he would need all express versions (which would become a storage pig)

Comment: Remember, your students can get VS2010 Pro and more for free from https://www.dreamspark.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per [this pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/useterms/visual%20studio%20.net%20professional_2003_english_be8aa149-b0fd-494d-a902-07fdb2007b90.pdf) (Page 1)

> A single license for the Software may not be shared or used concurrently by multiple end users.

It looks to me that it can be installed on multiple machines as long as it is not used concurrently by multiple end users.

Also, reviewing [this pdf](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d&displaylang=en) (Page 9) I see

> **Visual Studio 2010 Client Edition-Only Licensing**
>   Visual Studio 2010 products can be purchased without an MSDN subscription in certain channels. (See the How to Buy section of this paper for more details).The user can install and use the Visual Studio client software on as many devices as they like. However, the products are licensed on a per-user basis—that is, only the licensed user can use the software.

Comment: actually I think this license agreement is quite reasonable.  I can install my ONE copy at home, on my laptop, and at work (three installations) and not be in violation of the EULA.  Unlike many other applications out there that would require you to buy a copy for each install (NERO for example)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/fc574f4c-1beb-4930-b389-30abac4de9bb) thread on Visual Studio Developer Center/Visual Studio Forums. (And this comes from the Microsoft licensing specialists)