# One VS license for both work and personal use?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, licensing

As per this question ([Can I install VS on two machines with one license?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220295/can-i-install-vs-on-two-machines-with-one-license)) as a single person I can use VS on as many computers as I wish, even at work and at home. My question is, can I use the one license to both write software at work for my company's internal use, *and* write my own independent software from home that I sell? (My company paid for the license not me).

My guess would be no, but I can't find anything to support or contradict that.

(disclaimer: I understand that responses are not official legal advice)

Comment: SO is not a "legal advice site" .. in any case software is often licensed per-user or per-seat. See the fine print.

Comment: @pst Sorry; do you know anywhere else that I could/should ask this question?

Comment: I would imagine Developers might be a *little* more applicable .. maybe. Although your companies license manager and/or Microsoft support are alternate channels.

Comment: When installing single user programs on multiple computers it is usually assumed that only one instance will be utilized at time. Such as using a laptop when you're away from your desktop, not as a "free for all".  Your company is not at liberty to give you the license, that is what most would call software piracy.  As was pointed out, software is usually sold per seat/user!  Do everyone a favor and purchase your own software, it helps keep the cost down.

Comment: @RobertoWilko I am the user that the software is licensed to.

Comment: @Sahuagin - Apologies..I must have been confused. You explained that your company paid for the license not you. Unless they gifted it to you, I would say they own the license and you are the registered user entered at time of setup, two different things. With VS companies purchasing multiple licenses must have a business account to manage and secure the licenses. The best thing would be to ask your boss, but I can assure Microsoft does indeed care if you're using it outside of the license agreement that was agreed to upon install.

Comment: @RobertoWilko If it is per-user licensing, how is that different? I am licensed to use the software.

Comment: @Sahuagin -There are fine lines drawn, in my opinion, with your issue. If they do indeed own the license and your boss allows you to install it on your machine at home to perform company related work - great! I would submit, the second you switch from doing their work to your work, you're violating copyright and end-user agreements, even if your boss doesn't care.  Obviously, in this day and age with bit-torrent and so called "digital sharing"(?) I would be labeled a prude. It's sort of a moral issue really. Especially considering you plan to profit from your code.

Comment: @RobertoWilko You're basically saying that you wouldn't like it. I don't care whether you like it, is there a legitimate reason why this is against the EULA? Your comments are not helpful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14231/discussion-between-roberto-wilko-and-sahuagin)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just say this. VS allows multiple installs for a single license. However, the installs are only allowed to be used by a single user. Extrapolating that, I would say, if your business has 5 licenses, and THEY allow you to use one, then you can install it at home according to the license. More importantly, I would ask your company if their policy allows that.

The VS license allows multiple installs for a single user. Your company, on the other hand, may not like the idea of you moonlighting with their software. =)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350

Page 8 states that Visual Studio is an 'Individual Development Tool' and is licensed per user.

Comment: That seems logical, that Microsoft wouldn't care, but that my company would. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm glad someone actually read the license before feeling compelled to give advice..